# JSON Schema: Validate that exactly one property is present

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I would like validate a JSON structure in which either the `userId` key or the `appUserId` key must be present (exactly one of them - not both).

For example,

```
{ "userId": "X" }
{ "appUserId": "Y" }
```

Are valid, but:

```
{ "userId": "X", "appUserId": "Y"}
{ }
```

Are not.

How can I validate this condition using a JSON Schema? I have tried the `oneOf` keyword, but it works for values, not keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "userId": {"type" : "number"},
        "appUserId": {"type" : "number"},
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
             "type": "object",
             "required": ["userId"],
        },
        {
             "type": "object",
             "required": ["appUserId"],
        }
    ],
}


validate({'userId': 1}, schema) # Ok
validate({'appUserId': 1}, schema) # Ok
validate({'userId': 1, 'appUserId': 1}, schema) # ValidationError
```

Comment: How to deal with a similar situation where we have more than 2 properties out of which we need to choose any 1 example: Choosing any 1 out of 4 types.

Comment: how to validate, only one key. {'userId':1,'userId:2'} should not be valid as it should only have one userId at most

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of min/maxProperties and additionalProperties in schema:

```json
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "userId": { "type": "string" },
        "appUserId": { "type": "string" },
    },
    "maxProperties": 1,
    "minProperties": 1,
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

```js
// invalid cases
{ }
{ "userId": "111", "appUserId": "222" }
{ "anotherUserId": "333" }

// valid cases
{ "userId": "111" }
{ "appUserId": "222" }
```